# What should be the reponse code when validation errors happen?

Tags: web-services, http, api, error-code

I'm implementing an API. The API accepts/returns JSON content type.
Now, suppose that the data submitted by some POST request is not valid, like a missing attribute, or a duplication exists for the same data.
What is the standard HTML response code in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two answers:

If you have submitted a form, just return `200 - OK` with HTML explaining why the object was not created.

If you have an API you should use the following

**200 OK**

- When the request was OK and returned the proper data.

**201 CREATED**

- The call was successful and the new object created.

**400 BAD REQUEST**

- Invalid request URI
- Invalid HTTP Header
- Receiving an unsupported, nonstandard parameter
- Receiving an invalid HTTP Message Body

**401 UNAUTHORIZED**

- Authorization problems. E.g. wrong API key, etc.

**403 FORBIDDEN**

- Properly authorized, but not allowed.

**404 NOT FOUND**

- The resource does not exist (e.g. on Read or Update)

**405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED**

- Use in situations that a given REST method is not allowed. E.g. a POST on a single resource, or a DELETE on the entire collection of resources.

**409 CONFLICT**

- When an update fails, send "Conflict" to allow the client side to resolve the conflict themselves and retry.

**500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR**

- Internal error. This is the default code that is used for all unrecognized errors.

**501 NOT IMPLEMENTED**

- Use for expected, but not yet implemented features.

Answer (score 2):

The error lies on the client side, so you want to use a [4xx](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4) status code. I'd go with [400 - Bad Request](http://restpatterns.org/HTTP_Status_Codes/400_-_Bad_Request):

> The request could not be understood by
>   the server due to malformed syntax.
>   The client SHOULD NOT repeat the
>   request without modifications.

Answer (score 0):

The closest i can find would be `400 Bad Request`.

Answer (score 0):

As Ariejan said you should base your API in the HTTP codes already defined. If you want to send a error message the best way should be not use the HTTP message, but better include the message in the response body, JSON formatted.

Answer (score 0):

422 Unprocessable Entity (see [RFC 4918, Section 11.2](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc4918.html#rfc.section.11.2))